# How to compare two strings, which(both of them) are stored in char double pointer?

Tags: c

```
char ** magazine;
char ** ransom;
*magazine = malloc(sizeof(char*) * m);
for(int magazine_i = 0; magazine_i < m; magazine_i++){
   magazine[magazine_i] = (char *)malloc(10240 * sizeof(char));
   scanf("%s",magazine[magazine_i]);
}
*ransom = malloc(sizeof(char*) * n);
for(int ransom_i = 0; ransom_i < n; ransom_i++){
   ransom[ransom_i] = (char *)malloc(10240 * sizeof(char));
   scanf("%s",ransom[ransom_i]);
}
```

Now I want to compare the string stored in ransom to magazine. How it can be done? Please help

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: Please show a [MCVE]

Comment: Read about [strcmp](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `strcmp` in a loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (strcmp(magazine[i], ransom[i]) == 0) {
        ...
    }
}
```

But if (as the title suggests) `ransom` is declared as a pointer to pointer to `char`:

```
char **ransom;
```

you don't want the dereference operator `*`

```
*ransom = malloc(sizeof(char*) * n);
```

should be

```
ransom = malloc(sizeof(char*) * n);
```